# Text Wrap in J2ME

Tags: string, java-me, midp, lcdui

I am working on a small J2ME project and i need to wrap text displayed on a form as it extends beyond view.

I am using the Nokia IDE

This is my code below:

```
aboutScreen.append(new StringItem("QY is a simplified web application that enables people all over the world access...", null));
```

How do I do so that when it gets to the end of the screen it moves to the next line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the API incorrectly - the 1st parameter is the label, and not the actual text.

Try `new StringItem(null, "QY is a simplified web application that enables people all over the world access...")` instead - and the text should auto-wrap when the space for it runs out.

You can read about it in the JavaDoc - check the **Item Sizes** section:
http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Item.html#sizes